# Jquery executes Error section by default - Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am new to Ajax and JQuery. I am attempting to insert data into my database without submitting the form. The data gets inserted into the table but:

1. I am not able to get either the Error Message or Success Message on My jsp. It Comes as `[object Object]`
2. Looks like the success section of the Jquery is not executed at all

My Jquery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //On Button Click
                $("#countrybutton").click(function () {
                    //Get Text box values

                    var country = $("#country").val();
                    var continent = $("#continent").val();
                    var region = $("#region").val();
                    var population = $("#population").val();
                    var capital = $("#capital").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'do?MOD=BOK&ACT=domcountry&country=' + country + "&continent=" + continent + "&region=" + region + "&population=" + population + "&capital=" + capital,
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "Post",
                        success: function (result) {
                           $("#message").text(result);
                            //Clear Textbox data
                            $("#country").val('');
                            $("#continent").val('');
                            $("#region").val('');
                            $("#population").val('');
                            $("#capital").val('');
                        },
                        error: function (responseText) {
                            $("#message").text(responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

My JSP

```
  <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">
                <th colspan="5" align="left" scope="col"></th>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" id="message" style="color: red; font-size: 14px;"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Country Name</td>
                    <td style="color: red">*</td>
                    <td><label>
                            <input name="country" value="${country}" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"  type="text" id="country"/>
                        </label></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Continent Name</td>
                    <td style="color: red">*</td>
                    <td><label>
                            <input name="continent" value="${continent}" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"   type="text"  id="continent"/>
                        </label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Region</td>
                    <td style="color: red">*</td>
                    <td><label>
                            <input name="region" value="${region}"  onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"  type="text" id="region"/>
                        </label></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Population</td>
                    <td style="color: red">*</td>
                    <td><label>
                            <input name="population" value="${population}"  type="text"  id="population"/>
                        </label></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>Capital</td>
                    <td style="color: red">*</td>
                    <td><label>
                            <input name="capital" value="${capital}"   type="text" id="capital"/>
                        </label></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1">
                <th colspan="5" align="left" scope="col"></th>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><div align="right">
                            <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" class="redButton" />
                        </div></td>
                    <td><label>
                            <input name="Submit" class="redButton" type="button" id="countrybutton" onclick="MM_validateForm('country', '', 'R', 'continent', '', 'R', 'region', '', 'R', 'population', '', 'R',
                                            'capital', '', 'R');
                                    return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit" />
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

And My servlet section:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
                        String country = request.getParameter("country");
                        String continent = request.getParameter("continent");
                        String region = request.getParameter("region");
                        int population = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("population"));
                        String capital = request.getParameter("capital");
                        String returnMessage;
                        if (Countries.addCountry(country, continent, region, population, capital)) {
                            returnMessage = "Record Inserted.";
                        } else {
                            returnMessage = "Unable to Insert Record.";
                            try {
                                throw new InsertException("Unable to Insert record");
                            } catch (InsertException ex) {
                                log.debug(ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                        new Gson().toJson(returnMessage, response.getWriter());
                        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try remove this line:

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

and to get exception in Ajax error, you will need set http code 500 in response, add this inside your "else":

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

Servlet final:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
String country = request.getParameter("country");
String continent = request.getParameter("continent");
String region = request.getParameter("region");
int population = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("population"));
String capital = request.getParameter("capital");
String returnMessage;
if (Countries.addCountry(country, continent, region, population, capital)) {
    returnMessage = "Record Inserted.";
} else {
    returnMessage = "Unable to Insert Record.";
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    try {
        throw new InsertException("Unable to Insert record");
    } catch (InsertException ex) {
        log.debug(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
new Gson().toJson(returnMessage, response.getWriter());
```

Comment: Thanks This actually Worked.